# Calling a function in java

Tags: java, spring

I'm using SpringBoot and I have a REST API.

Now I want to get the settings object so I can use its properties. But this call is from inside my app from another .java file. How do I do this? Does it make sense make an Http request inside my own app? How do I handle this??

SettingsInterFace

```
public interface SettingsRepository extends JpaRepository<Settings,Long> {}
```

SettingsController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SettingsController {

    @Autowired
    private SettingsRepository settingsRepository;

    @GetMapping("/settings")
    public List<Settings> getSettingss() {
        return settingsRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/settings/{id}")
    public Settings getSettings(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return settingsRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/settings")
    public Settings createSettings(Settings Settings) {
        return settingsRepository.save(Settings);
    }

    @PutMapping("/settings")
    public Settings updateSettings(Settings Settings) {
        return settingsRepository.save(Settings);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/settings/{id}")
    public boolean deleteSettings(@PathVariable Long id) {
        settingsRepository.deleteById(id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Docker

```
public class Docker {

    private static DockerClient dockerClient;

    // #####################  BUILD CONNECTION WITH DOCKER ####################################
    static {

        try {
            Settings settings = ;
            DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                    .withDockerHost("tcp://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort())
                    .withDockerConfig("/home/user/.docker/config.json")
                    .build();

            dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    public static DockerClient dockerClient() {
        return dockerClient;
    }

    // #########################################################################################
}
```

Comment: Rather than hitting this existing endpoint, why don't you refactor the shared code to a common location, and then call it wherever you need it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have a REST for settings so my angular frontend can print related stuff. But in my app I have a Docker.java where I need the settings object.

Comment: can you make an example please?

Comment: When you implement the JPA repository interface, you're exposing a data source as a CRUD web service.  You could either make an HTTP connection if it's important to keep those settings separate OR you could just use a JDBC based repository to access it without an HTTP client.  Exposing it on the web implies that this data is shared by a lot of apps.  If it's not, you shouldn't expose the CRUD web service.

Comment: I'm only using JPArepository so the app can access it. I need to show those settings details on the page, but I also need that data on the backend